How can Blowfish be resistant against differential cryptanalysis if it doesn't have S-boxes tuned for that?
The S-boxes used in DES were carefully tuned for resistance against differential cryptanalysis, a technique not known to the public at that time but known to designers of DES. It was later discovered that even a small change to DES would make it more susceptible to differential cryptanalysis.
My understanding is that Blowfish isn't particularly vulnerable to differential cryptanalysis. However, its S-boxes are based on "nothing up my sleeve numbers", digits of pi. So the designer of Blowfish couldn't tune the S-boxes for resistance against differential cryptanalysis.
How can Blowfish therefore be resistant against differential cryptanalysis, if its S-boxes weren't tuned for that but rather used "nothing up my sleeve numbers"? Is this related to the big size of the Blowfish S-boxes, the highly complex key schedule, or the fact that the S-boxes are dependent on the key?

An aside: Digits of pi may seem to be "nothing up my sleeve", but you can in principle find a desired sequence of any length within the digits of pi. It may also be that some early digit sequences in PI just happen to work for a given application, but, let's say the early digits of e or sqrt(2) would not work. I find the "nothing up my sleeve" claim to be at best unconvincing. Who chose to use PI and not some other irrational number?? IMHO, "nothing up my sleeve" demands some scrutiny at minimum, and is not to be trusted at maximum :)

The short answer is to have more rounds. This article provides an equation to  determine the number of chosen plaintexts required for a differential cryptographic attack on a Blowfish with multiple rounds, The formula is :
$$
2^{2 + 7 \left( \frac{r - 2}{2} \right)} 
$$
where $r$ represents the number of rounds. For example, with $16$ rounds, this calculation yields $ 2^{51} $ chosen plaintexts.
To achieve security for a 64-bit plaintext size, you need at least $ 2^{64} $ chosen plaintexts. Using the formula provided:
$$
2^{2 + 7 \left( \frac{r - 2}{2} \right)} = 2^{64}
$$
Solving for $ r $:
$$
2 + 7 \left( \frac{r - 2}{2} \right) = 64 
$$
$$
7 \left( \frac{r - 2}{2} \right) = 62 
$$
$$
\frac{r - 2}{2} = \frac{62}{7} 
$$
$$
r - 2 = \frac{124}{7} 
$$
$$
r = \frac{124}{7} + 2 \approx 19.71
$$
Therefore, a minimum of 20 rounds is required to reach the 64-bit security level.

Yes, the TEA algorithm is just designed to prove that even a simple round function can be secure with enough rounds.
